# Nginx and Apache working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx

I'm trying to have different applications on the same server. The main app is written in Ruby on Rails 4 alongside 2 PHP systems. Up until now I have had a simple Apache with a virtual host listening on port 80 and my PHP apps deployed under /var/www/.

Now I installed Nginx and when I set it up and I point to /var/www/rails-apps/ I don't know how to get the others application (/www/var/wiki and /www/var/chat) working. I've tried with changing ports for Apache but nothing worked for me.

Could you guide me about how to front a solution here?

Comment: You don't need two web servers, you might use some rack based application server back proxied by apache on another virtual server. You can use phusion passenger for instance, http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Comment: I forgot to mention it, I already have Passenger installed but I don't know how to make all these redirections